# fix for X-Authentication-Warning

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

i am getting some line of message in /var/spool/mail/ec2-user log file, when alert mail is not delivering to the user by using cronjob .

all emails sent from my amazon ec2 server via php programs such as windows live mail would have following header message

```
X-Authentication-Warning: ec2-user set sender to email using -f
```

i m getting this problem from recently only, at the beginning i didnot face this problem

i m using following windows live mail configuration

```
ini_set('SMTP', "smtp.live.com");
ini_set('smtp_port', "25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', "admin@mail.com");
ini_set('password',"password");
ini_set('Security','Enable TLS');
```